# Stack trace: Call to TTSCOMMIT without first calling TTSBEGIN

Tags: transactions, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

We have been facing this strange error on some insert/update/delete calls to some of the table methods where there is some other code inside these methods which is also using `ttsbegin`/`ttscommit` in AX 2012 Feature pack.

`ttsbegin` and `ttscommit` is balanced on all levels and declared on same levels every place they are used inside code.

I find this behavior very strange as same code is working in another environment which does have same specifications.

Could it be some kernel related issue?

Same error does sometimes occur when deleting multiple lines on CustTable form for instance. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Are there any try/catch blocks that are also around the transaction? In certain circumstances those can call ttsabort prior to the ttscommit, causing an imbalance in TTS levels. I would also recommend running step-by-step in the debugger to identify if another method is throwing the error (keeping an eye on the TTS level on the bottom of the debug window).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/27243714/4509

Comment: Try/catch is not the cause, as any throw aborts the transaction.

Comment: Check your client/kernel version. I experienced some similar behavior where the versions did not match. Also I assume you already took care of the usual suspects (compile, full cil compile, aos restart, database sync).

Answer (score 2):

As general information to transaction in combination with try-catch:

> The general rule is that exceptions are caught in the outer most
>   catch, where the ttslevel is 0. This means that if you put a
>   transaction around a try/catch, your exceptions will not be caught.
>   The following two jobs demonstrate that:
>
> Transaction inside try/catch:
>       try
>       {
>           ttsBegin;
>           throw error("an error");
>           ttsCommit;
>       }
>       catch
>       {
>           info("error caught");
>       }
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Error an error
> Info error caught
> ```
>
> Try/catch inside transaction:
>       ttsBegin;
>       try
>       {
>           throw error("an error");
>       }
>       catch
>       {
>           info("error caught");
>       }
>       ttsCommit;
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Error an error
> ```
>
> As you can see, the error is not caught when the transaction is around
>   the try catch.
>
> However, there are two exceptions to this rule. The following code
>   demonstrates that UpdateConflict and DupplicateKeyException can be
>   caught inside a transaction.
>       Set             set = new Set(Types::Enum); // a set containing all possible exceptions
>       SetEnumerator   se;                         // enumerator used to loop though the set with exception
>       Exception       exception;                  // used to cast the value from the set
>       boolean         caughtInside;
>       ;
>
> ```
> // add all exception to a set
> set.add(Exception::Break);
> set.add(Exception::CLRError);
> set.add(Exception::CodeAccessSecurity);
> set.add(Exception::DDEerror);
> set.add(Exception::Deadlock);
> set.add(Exception::DuplicateKeyException);
> set.add(Exception::DuplicateKeyExceptionNotRecovered);
> set.add(Exception::Error);
> set.add(Exception::Info);
> set.add(Exception::Internal);
> set.add(Exception::Numeric);
> set.add(Exception::PassClrObjectAcrossTiers);
> set.add(Exception::Sequence);
> set.add(Exception::Timeout);
> set.add(Exception::UpdateConflict);
> set.add(Exception::UpdateConflictNotRecovered);
> set.add(Exception::Warning);
>
> // create enumerator
> se = set.getEnumerator();
>
> // loop all exceptions
> while(se.moveNext())
> {
>     // set flag false
>     caughtInside = false;
>     // begin outer try catch
>     try
>     {
>         ttsBegin;
>         // begin inner try catch
>         try
>         {
>             // cast exception
>             exception = se.current();
>             // trhow exception
>             throw exception;
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             // set flag to indicate the exception was caught inside the transaction
>             caughtInside = true;
>
>             warning(strFmt("%1 can be caught inside transaction", exception));
>             // throw exception again to catch it outside of transaction
>             throw exception;
>         }
>         ttsCommit;
>     }
>     catch
>     {
>         // for once, it's ok to catch everyting :)  
>
>         if(caughtInside)
>         {
>             warning(strFmt("%1 can also be caught outside of the transaction", exception));
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             info(strFmt("%1 can only be caught outside of the transaction", exception));
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Info Info can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Warning can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Deadlock can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Error can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Internal can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Break can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info DDEerror can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Sequence can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Numeric can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info CLRError can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info CodeAccessSecurity can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Warning UpdateConflict can be caught inside transaction
> Warning UpdateConflict can also be caught outside of the transaction
> Info UpdateConflictNotRecovered can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Warning DuplicateKeyException can be caught inside transaction
> Warning DuplicateKeyException can also be caught outside of the transaction
> Info DuplicateKeyExceptionNotRecovered can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info Timeout can only be caught outside of the transaction
> Info PassClrObjectAcrossTiers can only be caught outside of the transaction
> ```
>
> It is also noteworthy that, when you enter a catch block, there has
>   been a implicit ttsabort, so the transaction has been rolled back.
>   However this is not true for UpdateConflict and DuplicateKeyException
>   when they were caught inside a transaction.

Source: http://www.artofcreation.be/2011/08/10/try-catch-and-transactions/

Answer (score 1):

Calling `return` between `ttsbegin` and `ttscommit` is a no-go.

Also, the problem may be caused by any imbalance introduced in any code called by the code, fx `insert` or `update` methods.

Comment: Pleas mark as accepted, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 0):

I have now localized the error in code. Deep down inside the code on 5th ttslevel there was a customization in an insert method of ContactPerson table in VAR layer .. I know its very strange but we have newly overtaken this customer so this was clearly sign of a poorly managed test environment. After removing one TTSCOMMIT which was one too many things have obviously started working. This was my first post in forum and I am impressed with the response you guys have given me. I am very grateful for all help you guys have given on this case. I hope to return some in future :)